# How to sleep or delay current thread for some time in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I tried with following code. but it's not working. **threads.h** file is not detected by the compiler.

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Time: %s", ctime(&(time_t){time(NULL)}));
    thrd_sleep(&(struct timespec){.tv_sec=1}, NULL); // sleep 1 sec
    printf("Time: %s", ctime(&(time_t){time(NULL)}));
}
```

Error is as follows

```
nuwan2@nuwan:~/Desktop/test$ gcc main.c -o pro
main.c:1:21: fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Can you add your error message?

Comment: main.c:1:21: fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: `gcc ` ---> `gcc -std=c11`

Comment: nuwan2@nuwan:~/Desktop/test$ gcc -std=c11 main.c -o pro
main.c:1:21: fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.